# WAFv2 Rule: How so specify word list when using "Contains Words" option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I am building a WAFv2 rule. I have list of **words** to allow. It is not clear from the documentation: How do I specify a word list? Is it comma separated ?, quoted, not quoted, etc. What is the correct syntax here?

[image]

Comment: I'd like to know that, too. Unfortunately, there are no details on the AWS-Documentation pages. Does anyone have any ideas?